# How to I find and replace after performing math on the string

Tags: python, python-3.x, replace, parameters, find

I have a file with with following strings

```
input complex_data_BITWIDTH;
output complex_data_(2*BITWIDTH+1);
```

Lets say BITWIDTH = 8

I want the following output

```
input complex_data_8;
output complex_data_17;
```

How can I achieve this in python with find and replace with some mathematical operation.

Comment: Do you need to perform arithmetic whenever there's something inside `()`?

Comment: Are the parentheses `()` guaranteed to be there when you need to perform the mathematical evaluation?

Comment: Are all uppercase strings in the file variables that need to be replaced?

Comment: I want to evaluate expression inside```()``` which is function of BITWIDTH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend looking into the `re` RegEx library for string replacement and string search, and the `eval()` function for performing mathematical operations on strings.

Example (assuming that there are always parentheses around what you want to evaluate) :

```
import re

BITWIDTH_VAL = 8
string_initial = "something_(BITWIDTH+3)"

string_with_replacement = re.sub("BITWIDTH", str(BITWIDTH_VAL), string_initial) 
# note: string_with_replacement is "something_(8+3)"

expression = re.search("(\(.*\))", string_with_replacement).group(1)
# note: expression is "(8+3)"

string_evaluated = string_with_replacement.replace(expression, str(eval(expression)))
# note: string_evaluated is "something_11"
```

Comment: Thanks! how do I make sure I evaluate expression within ```()``` which only has BITWIDTH in it. I don't want to evaluate ```abc (def*ghi) ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use variables for that if you know the value to change, one for the value to search and other for the new value

```py
BITWIDTH = 8
NEW_BITWIDTH = 2 * BITWIDTH + 1

string_input = 'complex_data_8;'
string_output = string_input.replace(str(BITWIDTH), str(NEW_BITWIDTH))
```

if you don't know the value then you need to get it first and then operate with it

```py
string_input = 'complex_data_8;'
bitwidth = string_input.split('_')[-1].replace(';', '')
new_bitwidth = 2 * int(bitwidth) + 1
string_output = string_input.replace(bitwidth, str(new_bitwidth))
```